# How to get data from mysql and view that data in android application?

Tags: java, android, html, mysql

I have a project that my backend is html and my frontend is android application. I am adding new quotes thru html and store it in MySQL. The quotes that was store will be added and view in the android app.

this is my code to display the quote in the app. I just store automatically the some quotes inside because i need to test if the next quote button is working. I don't how i will call the quotes that was in the database

```
Random random = new Random();
    TextView textQuot;
    Button buttonQuot;
    ImageView backmenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_motivquotes);

        textQuot = findViewById(R.id.textViewNextQuote);
        buttonQuot = findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQuote);
        backmenu = findViewById(R.id.backmenu);

        backmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(myIntent1);
            }
        });

        buttonQuot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayQuote();

            }
        });

        displayQuote();
    }

    public void displayQuote(){

        int randNum = random.nextInt((5+1)-1)+1;
        String randQuote="";

        switch(randNum){
            case 1:
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote1);
                break;
            case 2:
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote2);
                break;
            case 3:
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote3);
                break;
            case 4:
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote4);
                break;
            case 5:
                randQuote = getString(R.string.quote5);
                break;
        }
        textQuot.setText(randQuote);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backend isn't HTML.  HTML is a display language-  it's a front end only technology.  It's just for a web front end. And HTML can't talk to a database-  there's no logic in HTML.  What it sounds like is you don't have a backend, or you don't know what you actually have.

What you need is a webservice that can access your DB and send data from it to whomever requests it.  But I suggest you first find out what your actual architecture is, because you don't seem to know it.